# Ionic FCM Token Invalid

Tags: android, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm trying to send a notification to a single device. Since I can't install an android emulator on my computer, I tested my program by installing apk on my phone, which prevents me from seeing the console messages. I get a token with the getToken () process, then I use this token as follows:

```js
sendNotification() 
{  
let body = {
    "notification":{
      "title":"New Notification has arrived",
      "body":"Notification Body",
      "sound":"default",
      "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
      "icon":"fcm_push_icon"
    },
   
  
    "data":{
      "param1":"value1",
      "param2":"value2"
    },
      "to":toKey,
    
  }
  let options = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
  this.http.post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",body,{
    headers: options.set('Authorization', key),
  })
    .subscribe((customer) => {
  console.log(customer);
},
  (err) => {console.log(err)});
}
```

This results in an error named "InvalidRegistration" in the console.

Comment: Please do not add sensitive data to your examples because it might get dangerous. You can debug your app to see the token in console with Chrome Dev Tools. And use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send the notification. You probably are using the wrong token.

Comment: Did you get device token using `getToken()`? you can check it using Google Chrome Developer tools.

Comment: yes getToken().